# Android room cannot find setter build error when using @PrimaryKey(autoGenerated = true)

Tags: android, android-room

I am trying to implement Room database in my apps. And I created a simple model class called "Word".

```
@Entity(tableName = "word_table")
public class Word {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;

    @NonNull
    private String word;

    public Word(@NonNull String word) {
        this.word = word;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getWord(){
        return this.word;
    }
}
```

But when I tried to build the apps. It says:

> error: Cannot find setter for field.
>       private int id;

So I tried to add a setter for the "id" myself like:

```
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

The full class looks like this:

```
@Entity(tableName = "word_table")
public class Word {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;

    @NonNull
    private String word;

    public Word(@NonNull String word) {
        this.word = word;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getWord(){
        return this.word;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't resolve the problem. So what is the proper way to use an auto-generated id in room?

Comment: Can you update full edited Word class ?

Comment: question updated, thanks

Comment: try to add setter for String word too.